# Understanding the function of Boost capacitor

Tags: voltage, mosfet, current, current-measurement, mosfet-driver

I'm going through this MOSFET Driver IC - [MIC5021](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20005677A.pdf).

Since this is a high side switch, the gate voltage should be higher than the source voltage, which would be the Source voltage, Vdd.
According to the datasheet,

[image]

If the vdd voltage is 12V, then the gate voltage typ would be 18V, which seems logical. We might need to select the MOSFET's gate-source threshold voltage according to this.

One small question is what would be the gate voltage if the Vdd is 24V? What can be assumed so as to select the MOSFET gate - source threshold voltage?

But my actual question is how does the Boost capacitor help? Does the boost capacitor help to boost the Vdd voltage and provide the boost voltage to the GATE pin?

Also, different configurations are mentioned in Figures 6-1, 6-2 & 6-3. Do small capacitors imply small time constant, hence charging happens faster? But in that case, for high voltage configurations, the capacitor value should be less right?
But for the highest voltage config of figure 6-3, 20V to 36V, the cap recommended is 10nF. But for 12V-36V configuration, the cap is lesser 2.7nF?
Unable to understand this clearly. Request some help on this.

Comment: Like I said on the other question -- there's not really much to read into it, as the "charge pump" block is undefined; this is a question for Microchip themselves, likely no one out here will have an explanation. It's a strange device; it's not the usual bootstrap driver. While I can't explain the problems you're having, I can suggest avoiding this strange device entirely.

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for your clarification. Could you please clarify about my understandings of the the MOSFET boost voltage and the capacitor rise timing understandibng?

Comment: Is there some reason you think you need this component? And have you checked availability? It can be very risky to use a proprietary component with no direct cross.

Comment: Operationally, they seem to be making a higher voltage supply, so that -- whereas most drivers work Vgs, this works just Vg -- so for example a 24V supply should have about 36V boost so the gate pin can swing 0...36V (minus saturation), and they just assume that will do the job in terms of Vgs (for example, assuming S isn't shorted to GND). What value capacitor they want, and how it's connected, are anyone's guesses short of an internal diagram.